# Make an HTTP call synchronous

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, http, asynchronous

I am using Flutter to develop an app. Based on the response from a REST API, I need to route to different screens. As HTTP calls in Flutter are asynchronous, I am struggling to keep it blocked until the response is received. Before the response is received, the routing logic is executed and routing occurs based on previously initialized values. How can I make call synchronously?

I tried using *package:sync_http/sync_http.dart* as below, but it always fails. There is not enough documentation with the package either.

```
SyncHttpClientRequest request = SyncHttpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse('http://{serveraddress}:{port}/{apiname}/$param1/$param2'));
SyncHttpClientResponse response = request.close();
```

Comment: As the documentation says `This library should probably only be used to connect to HTTP servers that are hosted on 'localhost'` you may have use `http` library.

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh - can you please elaborate more how can I use http lib to make synchronous call.

Comment: Why do you need to make synchronous calls for an inherently asynchronous operation?  Why can't you use `await`, which allows you to structure your code to look similar to synchronous code?

Comment: @saurabh you can make the function `async` and  use `await` for calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Flutter [HTTP](https://pub.dev/packages/http) or [DIO](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package.

You can make an asynchronous call using the *await* keyword.

For example:

```
var response = await http.post(url, body: your request body);
```

The above line of code will wait until it gets the response from HTTP.
Make sure to encode/decode your data.